# Comparar la entrada con un string en trigger MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, tsql

Tengo el campo1 que fue modificado por el trigger before_insert_tabla pasandolo a upperCase y estoy intentando que el campo1 en el after_insert_tabla sea comparado con un texto, la idea es que este campo1 solo sea "ABIERTO" o "CERRADO" cualquier otro texto esta mal por asi decirlo y lo inserte en una tabla de errores de carga.

Intenté con lo siguiente.

```
IF (new.tipo_contrato <> 'ABIERTO' || new.tipo_contrato <>'CERRADO') THEN
    insert into errores_carga(contrato_compranet, mensaje, campo, archivo)
    values(
    cast(new.id + 1 as char)
    , concat('Tipo de contrato no definido', new.tipo_contrato), 10, 'SICOPU');
END IF;
```

La cuestion es que aunque este dentro de los parametros ("ABIERTO" o "CERRADO") realiza el insert en la tabla, cuando no deberia ser así.

tambien intente con la funcion STRCMP() pero es la misma situación.
Agradeceria su ayuda.

Gracias.

Comment: or? no deberia ser and?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno despues de darle vueltas así quedó

```
DECLARE estado_valido BOOLEAN;

IF NEW.tipo_contrato = 'ABIERTO' OR NEW.tipo_contrato = 'CERRADO' THEN
    SET estado_valido = TRUE;
ELSE
    SET estado_valido = FALSE;
END IF;

 IF NOT estado_valido THEN
   insert into errores_carga(contrato_compranet, mensaje, campo, archivo)
    values(
    cast(new.id + 1 as char)
    , "Tipo de contrato no definido", 10, 'x');
END IF;
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema no tiene nada que ver con el pasar a mayúsculas o lo que se haga en el *before insert*.

El error está en tu condición del IF:

```
IF (new.tipo_contrato <> 'ABIERTO' || new.tipo_contrato <>'CERRADO')
```

Esta siempre que `tipo_contrato` tenga algún valor va a devolver verdadero y por tanto siempre va a ejecutar el INSERT. El único caso dónde no lo va a ejecutar es si `tipo_contrato` es NULL.

Recuerda que el operador booleano OR, en este caso representado por `||` devuelve verdadero si uno de los operadores es verdadero, falso solo si ambos son falsos y null si ambos operadores son null o uno es falso y el otro null.

Entonces, veamos los resultados:

| tipo_contrato | tipo_contrato <> 'ABIERTO' (a) | tipo_contrato <> 'CERRADO' (b) | a OR B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OTRO | Verdadero | Verdadero | Verdadero |
| ABIERTO | Falso | Verdadero | Verdadero |
| CERRADO | Verdadero | Falso | Verdadero |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Las expresiones booleanas no son esotéricas, si aún no las has masterizado, debes ir despacio con ellas y tomarte el tiempo de reflexionar, escribirla, hacer pruebas en papel o en SQL, entender por qué falla o por qué funciona.

Esta es la razón por la que estoy escribiendo esta respuesta, pues probablemente hayas llegado a tu [propia solución](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/600756/21) sin hacer esta reflexión y llegar a comprender exactamente por qué una falla y la otra funciona.

Estoy asumiendo que el campo `tipo_contrato` es `not null`, es decir, siempre va a tener un valor.

Si quieres saber primero si es el valor es inválido, la más simple que se me ocurre es usar el operador NOT IN:

```
IF new.tipo_contrato not in ('ABIERTO', 'CERRADO')
```

Pero IN es azúcar sintáctica que el motor siempre traduce en una serie de OR de comparaciones de igualdad, por lo que es equivalente a escribir:

```
IF not (new.tipo_contrato = 'ABIERTO' OR new.tipo_contrato = 'CERRADO')
```

Otra alternativa, como ya has descubierto, es probar si es válido, que puede ser más simple por no requerir negación. También se puede usando el operador IN:

```
IF new.tipo_contrato in ('ABIERTO', 'CERRADO')
```

Que, como hemos visto antes, se traduce a:

```
IF new.tipo_contrato = 'ABIERTO' OR new.tipo_contrato = 'CERRADO'
```

Si existe la posibilidad que el campo contenga NULL, hay que tenerlo en cuenta a la hora de escribir estas condiciones, por ejemplo, usando una llamada a COALESCE para dar un valor Default antes de hacer las comparaciones.

Mi sugerencia es que hagas las tablas de verdad para cada una de estas expresiones, eso te ayudará a aumentar tu comprensión de la lógica booleana en general.

Esa habilidad es vital para todo programador.